# Bitcast requires both operands to be pointer or neither error with Swift compiler

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I had a terrible error with Swift and I didn't find any help on Google despite a lot of researches.

> Bitcast requires both operands to be pointer or neither   %116 =
>   bitcast i8* %115 to %SS, !dbg !249 Invalid operand types for ICmp
>   instruction   %117 = icmp ne %SS %116, null, !dbg !249 PHI nodes must
>   have at least one entry.  If the block is dead, the PHI should be
>   removed!   %120 = phi i32  PHI node operands are not the same type as
>   the result!   %119 = phi i8* [ %116, %108 ] LLVM ERROR: Broken
>   function found, compilation aborted!

I really didn't know where this error occured because after some refactoring, I made changes in a lot of file.

I decided to create a post in Q&A-style to help other developers to find what this error means.

Hope it helps !

Answer (score 0):

After I commented/de-commented all the code of my project during hours, I finally found the line which causes the error posted in my original post.

```
class LoginAccountViewController : UIViewController
{    
    @IBOutlet var loginFacebook : UIButton?
    @IBOutlet var emailField : UITextField?

    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool)
    {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    }

    @IBAction func loginEmail(sender: AnyObject)
    {
        if let emailAddress = emailField?.text as? String // THIS IS THE BAD LINE
        {
        }
    }
}
```

The error was that I tried to make an unwrap downcast to an attribute named `text` which is not optional, because of the object which contains the attribute is optional. This was a big mistake.

The good solution was to make an unwrap downcast to the `emailField` attribute and then, the `text` attribute doesn't need to be unwrapped to access to its value.

```
if let emailAddress = emailField as? UITextField
{
    println(emailAddress.text)            
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue once. Suddenly I fixed it when I replaced line (skipBtn is an UIButton)

```
skipBtn.setTitleColor(.whiteColor(), forState: .Normal)
```

with

```
skipBtn.setTitleColor(UIColor.whiteColor(), forState: .Normal)
```

I don't know why but it seems to me that this feature when you remove extra class name is not supported for 100% yet.